# Ubuntu login loop after manually installing Nvidia Drivers

Tags: nvidia, login, nvidia-geforce

I am stuck in a login loop whenever I try and install Nvidia drivers. I am able to install fine through windows but I have been stuck all day trying to get this to work. I am unable to login to Ubuntu. My specs are a Geforce 260 and I installed the newest drivers from Nvidias website.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ? Why did you not use the driver in the Ubuntu repository ?

Comment: 16.04. I have tried the official one and it gives me a similar error. @Panther

Comment: After installing the driver, did you run `nvidia-xsettings` ?

Comment: I did not. I can't login. Do I do that under the `tty` menu?

Comment: yes try running that command in any terminal or boot to recovery mode and run it. Then reboot (or restart lightdm).

Comment: @Panther when I run `nvidia-xsettings` it says command is not found